# Remote access to IIS-express

Tags: iis, proxy, ssl-certificate, iis-express

Usually when I start my web application, the browser will open https://localhost:44305

But I want to reach the site from my phone. I've tried changing the applicationhost configfile, firewall inbound rules and all that. But then I found this little thing [iisexpress-github](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy/blob/master/README.md)

I type this in my console: *iisexpress-proxy https://localhost:44305 to 3005*

Which results in this line: *Proxying https://localhost:44305 to network interfaces:
        Ethernet: 192.168.10.41:3005
Listening... [press Control-C to exit]*

After following instructions, the browser gives following error: '*Aw snap! Something went wrong. Check your console to see the error.*'

And then I look at my console which says the following:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at Error (native)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1016:38)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:585:8)
```

Usually my site is https, but this seems only to proxy to normal http.

What to do?

Comment: The error message is clear that the self signed certificate is not trusted.

Comment: But I don't really know what that means?

Comment: Then you first need to understand what is HTTPS and why a certificate is needed, https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html and then what is a self-signed certificate, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate